# How to run compojure rest server?

Tags: jar, clojure, ring

I've created a rest server with compojure and ring.

I can run it with 'lein ring server'. I can build it with 'lein uberjar'. But how to run this jar like java -jar my.jar ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke `lein ring uberjar` to generate a self-start server you can run with

```
java -jar target/uberjar/yourproject-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

I suggest you to use the *standalone* one to avoid dealing with dependencies

Edited to include the specific command

Comment: This requires running 'lein ring uberjar' to build it or adding a main function to start the server